# Run python script IN TERMINAL after Lubuntu login?

Tags: python, startup, lubuntu

I've spent the night trying to figure out how to run a python script in a terminal at startup.

Adding it to init.d will run the script, but I don't see a terminal window or any other indication the script is running other than the audio output the python script produces. I would like to be able to see and interact with this script in a terminal just as if I'd ran it from a terminal.

My next successful step was to make a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart. My Exec is

```
Exec=lxterminal -e "python ~/scripts/myscript.py"
```

When I log in, I see a terminal window flash for just a brief moment - but then disappear. No sound is produced from the python script so I assume it quit running. How do I start a terminal window at system startup and run a Python script in it?

Answer (score 4):

It seems your script is running, but you want the term to stay open.  If that's the goal:

```
Exec=lxterminal -e "python ~/scripts/myscript.py && /bin/bash"
```

Should keep the term open for you...

Answer (score 1):

I also had experienced some problems with lxterminal as for calling it with the -e argument from inside a .desktop file.

The solution for me was the following:

1. Make an executable file, named `launch_myscript.sh` with the content: `lxterminal -e python ~/scripts/myscript.py`.
2. Point to this file at your `Exec` field of the .desktop file that you have placed

Tips: You can try to directly place in your `Exec` field `lxterminal -e python /home/username/scripts/myscript.py`. Note that it lacks the `"` and the `~`.

Are you sure that `python ~/scripts/myscript.py` doesn't produce any error that causes it to exit?